# Sonic Wall TZ 210 multiple lan subnets

Tags: sonicwall

We have a sonic wall tz210 with a local subnet of 192.168.200.x. We are looking to build another subnet 192.168.100.x.
Can the sonic wall except and route traffic from both subnets to one external Internet connection?

Answer (score 1):

That's generally what a multi-interface firewall does, typically when there's an internal network and a DMZ network (connected to different firewall interfaces) that both have hosts/devices that need internet connectivity.